# dealing with extra columns in Excel files - C#

Tags: c#, excel

In my application I need to read an excel file and display the headers(title) in a tabular format.
This works fine so far. But for some excel files it shows(excel file has 20 columns) some extra columns(column21, column22 etc). Not sure why its showing these extra columns
when I checked the excel file it has only 20 columns and 21 or 22 columns are completely empty.
Not sure why my its displaying these extra columns.
When I tried to debug the code "myReader.FieldCount" was showing 22 columns.
I tried to programmatically remove those columns which are empty.
But it raised someother issues with the row data. For some rows its shows only 18 or 15 columns as there 
is missing data for some columns.
Is there a better way of dealing with excel.
Here is my code

@@@@@@@@@@@@@

```
  if (sourceFile.ToUpper().IndexOf(".XLSX") >= 0)     // excel 2007 or later file    
                strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sourceFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=No;\"";
            else         // previous excel versions
                strConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + sourceFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;\"";

            OleDbConnection conn = null;
            StreamWriter wrtr = null;
            OleDbCommand cmd = null;
            OleDbDataReader myReader = null;

            try
            {
                conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
                conn.Open();

                cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + worksheetName + "]", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                wrtr = new StreamWriter(targetFile);

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    List<string> builder = new List<string>();
                    for (int y = 0; y < myReader.FieldCount; y++)
                    {                        
                        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myReader[y].ToString()))
                            builder.Add("\"" + myReader[y].ToString() + "\"");

                    }
                    wrtr.WriteLine(string.Join(",", builder));
                }
```

Comment: A few observations. If you only want to get the column headers, there's no need to loop through all the rows in the sheet with your DataReader; Just check the first row, assuming that's where they're located. You mention that you ignore empty fields in a row, yet you seem puzzled to why you only see X amount of them as output... which is it? Remember, spaces count as characters too, so if a cell appears empty, it might not be. Use string.Trim() or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (.NET 4.0 >) to make sure you aren't including "empty" whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a SELECT * list out the columns you want to select in:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM [" + worksheetName + "]", conn);
```

Comment: I don't have control over the number of columns, they change dynamically. It all depends on what file user uploads.

Comment: If you don't have control over the number of columns how do you tell what columns you want to get rid of?

Comment: I want all the columns in the excel sheet. But Its adding some additional columns which are empty. Not sure why these extra columns are being added

Comment: That is most likely a problem with the excel spreadsheet.  Just as a test, copy just the column you want from that excel file to a new one and see if the behavior changes.  If so, there is something in the excel file that is registering as a column.

Comment: looks like its problem with the excel file, But is there a way to fix this. User might use different excel files without knowing all these issue.

Comment: If you can't fix the excel files, then you have to do it through code.  I would see if you can find columns that are totally empty and clean them out in C#.  Or clean out rows with no header.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to judge and filter the columnname by regex
Once the column is empty, C# will auto generate the column name like 'F21' 'F22' (the 21 indicates the empty column is the 21st column)

```
DataTable x = ...  // x is DataTable Name
int index = ...    // index is the column sequence no.
string col = x.Columns[index].Columnname.ToString().Trim();    
if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(col, "^[A-Z]{1}[0-9]*"))
   // do something
```